# Azure function with HTTP trigger and blob output binding failed with 500 and no details

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, serverless-framework

I am trying to create a simple Azure function app that receives image binary from HTTP request and write to blob storage using C# and Serverless Framework.

The C# function code looks is as follow:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage;

namespace ThumbnailGenerator.Azure
{
    public static class ThumbnailGenerator
    {
        [FunctionName("upload")]
        [StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [Blob("input/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream inputImage,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            
            byte[] data = System.Convert.FromBase64String(requestBody);
            await inputImage.WriteAsync(data);

            return new OkObjectResult("Succeed:" + name);
        }
    }
}
```

My `host.json` looks as follow:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "extensions": {
        "blobs": {
            "maxDegreeOfParallelism": "4"
        }
    }
}
```

And the app is deployed using Serverless Framework

```
service: thumbnail-dotnet

frameworkVersion: '2'

provider:
  name: azure
  runtime: dotnet3.1
  region: East US

# List of plugins used by service. Must always include: - serverless-azure-functions
plugins:
  - serverless-azure-functions
  
functions:
  upload:
    handler: src/handlers/upload.main
    events:
      - http: true
        methods:
          - GET
        authLevel: anonymous
```

However, when I tested it, Azure always gave `500 Internal Server Error` without any details. No application insights traces, no logs, and the execution count is zero as well which is really confusing for me.

Here is the generated function.json on Azure

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-3.0.11",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ],
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "name": "req"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/ThumbnailGenerator.dll",
  "entryPoint": "ThumbnailGenerator.Azure.ThumbnailGenerator.Run"
}
```

I have been trying different ways to debug it for a week and couldn't find the cause.

Anyone can give some tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I run your code locally, following exception is displayed:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'upload'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Unable to resolve binding parameter 'name'. Binding expressions must map to either a value provided by the trigger or a property of the value the trigger is bound to, or must be a system binding expression (e.g. sys.randguid, sys.utcnow, etc.).

As mentioned in the error message, you have to specify the variable in the trigger. I guess, binding to the query-parameter is still not possible in Azure Functions.

So you have to specify it in the route:

```
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "{name}")] HttpRequest req,
```

Run it locally:

> upload: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/{name}

Complete code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage;

namespace ThumbnailGenerator.Azure
{
    public static class ThumbnailGenerator
    {
        [FunctionName("upload")]
        [StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "{name}")] HttpRequest req,
            [Blob("input/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream inputImage,
            string name,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            byte[] data = System.Convert.FromBase64String(requestBody);
            await inputImage.WriteAsync(data);

            return new OkObjectResult("Succeed:" + name);
        }
    }
}
```

Please find the working code on [GitHub](https://github.com/MarkusMeyer13/stackoverflow-function-storage-67943931)

Comment: Thank you @Markus Meyer. It worked. But as I understand, it is possible to bind query-parameter using Java for Azure function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.bindingname?view=azure-java-stable